# Are questions about translations to English on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I am thinking about questions such as *[Como traduzir para Inglês “que eu aconselho”?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1077)*, which asks for the English translation of a Portuguese phrase. I suppose that would be on-topic on [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/), if it explained the intended meaning. Is it also on-topic here?

Comment: Stupid user posted this on the wrong meta. And he's a mod. Oh, wait! :)

Comment: Thanks @ANeves, I couldn't find that.

Comment: No problem; thanks for bringing it up, it's a good point. I was trying to answer, then I saw the other thread in the list of "Related" questions on the sidebar. :)

Comment: @bfavaretto priceless :D

Comment: What is going on?! Why can't **I** answer this question?

Comment: @Jacinto it was closed as a duplicate. You can answer the other one.

Comment: Just joking. I thought it was marked duplicate in the site it migrated from. Didn't know about the other question here.